# Which Wick contractions are allowed?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, correlation-functions, wick-theorem

### TLDR:

> Given a Lagragian $\mathcal{L}$ depending on some fields $\{\phi_a\}$, which contractions between the fields are permissible?

### Example to illustrate my problem

Consider the following Lagragian
$$\mathcal{L}_{\mathrm{SQED}}=-\left(D^{\mu} \phi\right)^{*} D_{\mu} \phi-m^{2} \phi^{*} \phi-\frac{1}{4} F^{\mu \nu} F_{\mu \nu}-\frac{1}{2} \xi^{-1}\left(\partial^{\mu} A_{\mu}\right)^{2},$$
where $D_\mu := \partial_\mu-iqA_\mu.$ I would now like to evaluate the following expression
$$\int\langle 0\vert T[\phi(x_1)\phi(x_2)\phi^*(x_3)\phi^*(x_4) A_\mu(y)A^\mu(y) \phi^*(y)\phi(y)]\vert 0\rangle\, d^4y$$
using Wick's theorem, i.e. rewrite the time ordering operator as the normal ordering of the above expression + all possible Wick contractions. The expectation value of the normal ordered term will give zero and we are basically left with all the complete contractions.

The issue I have is that I don't really understand which fields can be contracted with which.. Can I contract the photon field $A_\mu$ with the complex scalar field $\phi$? Can I contract the complex conjugate of the scalar field $\phi^*$ with another complex conjugate field $\phi^*$, or just with $\phi$? I'm not really sure how one is supposed to determine if the contractions are allowed or not.

Comment: are $\phi^*$ and $\phi^\dagger$ the same?

Comment: @fqq Yes, that's my bad.

Comment: QFT for the Gifted Amateur does a nice explanation of this, IMO, page 171 onwards (and it's not hard to find online :)

Comment: @StudyStudy Thanks for the reference, I'll check it out tomorrow!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The allowed contractions are those of the fields which have a non-zero two-point function. You can check if their two-point function is non-zero by looking at their mode expansion. If, after multiplying them, you get a pair of $a$ and $a^\dagger$ for which $[a^\dagger,a]=1$, then their two-point function is non-zero.

In this case $A_\mu$ pairs only with itself and $\phi$ only with $\phi^*$.

Comment: What about derivatives of fields, i.e. can I check if the contraction between $\partial_\mu\phi(x)$ and $\phi^*(y)$ is allowed in the same way?

Comment: Yes, if two fields have a contraction even their derivatives do.

Comment: Just to make sure I understand correctly: If two fields have a non-zero contraction, then the contraction of the derivative of one of the fields with the other field will be (most likely) non-zero.

Comment: Correct. And also the contraction of the derivative of one with the derivative of the other. Of course, the contraction of the derivatives will have some factors of the momenta.